# SQL Query update for integer datatype

Tags: sql

Need a help with SQL
I have a table with EmployeeID as below

```
11
22
1
55
2
```

I wanted to trim the last digits of all the rows and get the output as

```
1
2
1
5
2
```

Comment: What have you tried?  this seems pretty straight foward update statement with string functions `Update TableName set EmployeeID = left(EmployeeID, 1) where len(EmployeeID)>1` assuming implicit casting on a int datatype.  Though this would Error out if there's a PK or unique index on the column.  Not sure what you'd ever really want to do this on what appears to be an ID field.

Comment: What is the type for employee id column?

Comment: the data type is integer

Comment: First of all what DB you use?

Comment: if we use "Update TableName set EmployeeID = left(EmployeeID, 1" it will delete the column with value 1 -xQbert

Comment: add `where len(employeeID)>1` (this assumes MSFT SQL SERVER or some engine supporting left and len functions)

Comment: Thanks xQbert ! I will try that

Comment: Not sure why it would delete the column with value 1.  left of 1 for 1 is 1.  so all the where clause would do is only update those records which are not 1 character in length.  with or without the where clause it should have worked. depending on volume, the where clause version may be slightly faster

Comment: I'm puzzled here. **(1)** is EmployeeID of text type or integer? **(2)** What is the reason for this update?

Comment: **(3)** do you have IDs with more than 2 digits? in case you do have, e.g. **123** - do you want to turn it to **12** or **1**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE this one

```
 CASE WHEN LEN(ColumnName)>1 THEN LEFT(ColumnName, LEN(ColumnName)-1) ELSE        ColumnName END
```

Comment: what happens if the LEN(ColumnName) =0

Comment: if it's Zero then execute else part

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
UPDATE your_table SET EmployeeID=SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(EmployeeID),1,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

cast int as varchar and use right to select as many digits as you need.

```
select cast(right(1,cast(EmployeeID as varchar)) as int)
```

actually just doing

```
select right(1,employeeId) should work too.
```

if you want to update table then

```
update table
set employeeid = right(1,employeeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET EmployeeID = LEFT (EmployeeID, CASE WHEN LEN(EmployeeID) > 1 THEN LEN(EmployeeID) - 1 ELSE 1 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the `left()` function.  It will automatically convert an integer into a string, and then the result back to an integer.  So the simplest statement is:

```
update t
    employeeId = left(employeeId, 1);
```

Note:  In some databases, this would be `substr(employeeId, 1, 1)` or `substring(employeeId, 1, 1)`.

Also, this statement does two implicit type conversions.

You can also add `where employeeId like '__%'` if you want to limit the `update` to rows that will actually change.